# How to put a default text in empty page?

Tags: templates, emptypage

I am currently writing my thesis and for that I use a default template found on internet. It use `\cleardoublepage` apparently. I have an issue because this template add empty page by default and my company ask me to put the default text "This page is empty" for security reason.

I am wondering if it possible, by adding a simple code some where, to add that text on all empty pages ?

Thanks a lot,

Cheers,

Eliott

Comment: This wastly depends on the document at hand, so without code.... no help

Comment: It is probably possible, however a bit more information then "template found on the internet" would be helpful...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's hard to know without seeing the class (template) you are using. But if, as is probably the case, the empty pages are being generated by a "standard" `\cleardoublepage` you might try adding to the preamble:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}%
\patchcmd{\cleardoublepage}
         {\hbox{}}
         {\centerline{This page deliberately left blank}}
         {}{}
```

(The stated reason, by the way, is completely weird. Why would someone tamper with a page by making it blank? Wouldn't they more likely tamper with a page by adding something? And anyway, if they wanted to remove a page, couldn't they just replace it with a page reading "This page deliberately left blank"? I have **never** been puzzled by a blank page in a sensible place. These silly rules ...)

Comment: And yes, I found that security specification stupid but you know security people, they are a bit paranoiac. :)